# Using dplyr In R, how do I set values of rows of a new column as the difference between another element on the same row and the overall category mean?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add to a tibble a column which contains values equal to the difference between a given row's value and the overall mean of all rows in that row's category. Below is a dummy tibble in the format of my data, containing elevations in meters above sea level of four sites in each of two US states. Column `elev_normalized` is included to hold calculated values.

```
> t <- tibble(
+   "us_state"          = c(rep("Louisiana",4),rep("Colorado",4)),
+   "site_n"            = rep(1:4,2),
+   "elev_m"            = c(2,2,3,1,1600,1610,1590,1601),
+   "elev_normalized"   = rep(NA,8))
> t
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  us_state  site_n elev_m elev_normalized
  <chr>      <int>  <dbl> <lgl>          
1 Louisiana      1      2 NA             
2 Louisiana      2      2 NA             
3 Louisiana      3      3 NA             
4 Louisiana      4      1 NA             
5 Colorado       1   1600 NA             
6 Colorado       2   1610 NA             
7 Colorado       3   1590 NA             
8 Colorado       4   1601 NA
```

I want to set the first element column `elev_normalized` equal to the difference between the first element of column `elev_m` and the mean of all values in column `elev_m` (i.e. as `2-mean(c(2,2,3,4))`). Said otherwise, I would like to express the elevation of each site in a state relative to the mean elevation of all four sites in the same state. How can I accomplish this using in `dplyer` or the larger `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it this way:

```r
library(dplyr)
t %>%
  group_by(us_state) %>%
  summarize(mu = mean(elev_m)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(t, ., by = "us_state") %>%
  mutate(elev_normalized = elev_m - mu) %>%
  select(-mu)
# # A tibble: 8 × 4
#   us_state  site_n elev_m elev_normalized
#   <chr>      <int>  <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1 Louisiana      1      2            0   
# 2 Louisiana      2      2            0   
# 3 Louisiana      3      3            1   
# 4 Louisiana      4      1           -1   
# 5 Colorado       1   1600           -0.25
# 6 Colorado       2   1610            9.75
# 7 Colorado       3   1590          -10.2 
# 8 Colorado       4   1601            0.75
```

Walk-through:

1. Group by `us_state` and calculate the mean;

   ```r
   t %>%
     group_by(us_state) %>%
     summarize(mu = mean(elev_m)) %>%
     ungroup()
   # # A tibble: 2 × 2
   #   us_state     mu
   #   <chr>     <dbl>
   # 1 Colorado  1600.
   # 2 Louisiana    2
   ```
2. Join this back onto the original `t`, which gives us `elev_m` and the mean `mu` side-by-sideL

   ```r
   ... %>%
     left_join(t, ., by = "us_state")
   # # A tibble: 8 × 5
   #   us_state  site_n elev_m elev_normalized    mu
   #   <chr>      <int>  <dbl> <lgl>           <dbl>
   # 1 Louisiana      1      2 NA                 2 
   # 2 Louisiana      2      2 NA                 2 
   # 3 Louisiana      3      3 NA                 2 
   # 4 Louisiana      4      1 NA                 2 
   # 5 Colorado       1   1600 NA              1600.
   # 6 Colorado       2   1610 NA              1600.
   # 7 Colorado       3   1590 NA              1600.
   # 8 Colorado       4   1601 NA              1600.
   ```
3. Do the subtract (and remove the temporary column `mu`).